# How can I differentiate ($2x+1$)($x-5$) by expanding then differentiating?

Tags: calculus

> The question is to differentiate ($2x+1$)($x-5$) by expanding then differentiating each term

But I am running into problems and am running into the wrong answer
I end up with

$4x-15$

but answer is $2x$$^2$($2x-3$)

How?

Comment: You cannot differentiate a quadratic and obtain a cubic.

Comment: That's the answer from my textbook (the one with cubic)

Comment: Textbooks are often known for being incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both answers are incorrect. The answer is $4x-9$ since $(2x+1)(x-5)=2x^2-9x-5$ and its derivative is $4x-9$.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those answers are incorrect. The expansion of $(2x+1)(x-5)$ is $(2x+1)(x-5)=2x^2-9x-5$.

The derivative is then $2\cdot2x^{2-1}-9\cdot1x^{1-1}=4x-9$.

Note that the derivative of a polynomial of degree $n\gt0$ is always a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Hence, it is obvious that the second answer given in your question is incorrect, as it shows the derivative of a polynomial of degree $2$ to be a polynomial of degree $3$.

Answer (score 0):

By the product rule
$$\frac{d}{dx} (2x+1)(x-5) = (x-5)(2) + (2x+1)(1) = 4x -9$$
And the other way round
$$\frac{d}{dx} (2x^2-9x-25)  =    2(2x) -9 = 4x-9$$